# jQuery mobile mySQL - UPDATE doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with my jquery mobile app.
I'm trying to update a few things in my database, but it doesn't work. I don't get any errors from JS or PHP files (unless I open update.php without submiting anything, but then the only errors are undefined indexes for values I bind with $_POST).
The weirdest part is that identical code for INSERT INTO is actually working.

Here is the working code:
-JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#saveForm").submit(function(){
    var formData=$(this).serialize();

    $.post('save.php',formData,processData).error(errorResponse);

    function processData(data){
        $("#popupSave").popup();
        $("#popupSave").popup("open");
    };

    function errorResponse(){
        alert("Something went wrong!");
    };

    return false; //Prevent the form from reloading
}); //end of submit function
}); //end of jquery document
```

-PHP:

```
<?php
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=titlesdbs";
$username="root";
$password="";

try
{
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
echo 'Connected!';
}
catch(PDOException $error)
{
echo 'Connection no established: ' . $error->getMessage();
}

$sql="INSERT INTO titlestbl (title, pages, date) VALUES(:title, :pages, :date)";
try {
    $st=$conn->prepare($sql);
    $st->bindValue(':title', $_POST['title'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $st->bindValue(':pages', $_POST['pages'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $st->bindValue(':date', $_POST['date'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $st->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
echo "Server error - Try again".$e->getMessage();
};
$conn=null;
?>
```

And the code that doesn't work:
-JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#updateForm").submit(function(){
    var formData=$(this).serialize();

    $.post('update.php',formData,processData).error(errorResponse);

    function processData(data){
        $("#popupUpdate").popup();
        $("#popupUpdate").popup("open");
    };

    function errorResponse(){
        alert("Something went wrong!");
    };

    return false; //Prevent the form from reloading
}); //end of submit function
}); //end of jquery document
```

-PHP:

```
<?php
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=titlesdbs";
$username="root";
$password="";

try
{
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
//echo 'Connected!';
}
catch(PDOException $error)
{
echo 'Connection no established: ' . $error->getMessage();
}

$sql="UPDATE titlestbl SET check=1, summary=':summary', quotes=':quotes', comments=':comments' WHERE id=:id";
try {
    $st=$conn->prepare($sql);
    $st->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $st->bindValue(':summary', $_POST['summary'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $st->bindValue(':quotes', $_POST['quotes'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $st->bindValue(':comments', $_POST['comments'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $st->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
echo "Server error - Try again".$e->getMessage();
};
$conn=null;
?>
```

Is it some stupid mistake I can't find or should I do it anothe way?

Answer (score 0):

You have quotes (`'`s) around the bound variables, which turns them into string literals and breaks your update. Remove them, and you should be OK:

```
$sql = "UPDATE titlestbl SET check=1, summary=:summary, quotes=:quotes, comments=:comments WHERE id=:id";
```

Comment: Only: "Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\update.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: summary in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\update.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: quotes in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\update.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: comments in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\update.php on line 22"
But that's when I open the file without submitting the form and that's all no other errors from PHP and no errors from JS.